# How do I use a local file as a database using _mysql?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to use a local file as a database; however, from all information on the internet I can only connect to a database through a network connection. `sqlite3` allowed me to specify a filename in as the first parameter in the connect function. How do I do this in `_mysql`?

This is how did it in `sqlite3`.

```
import sqlite3
db = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
```

Comment: What is `_mysql`? What are you even asking here?

Comment: I do the command `import _mysql` and then `db._mysql.connect("mydb.db")` and it thinks I'm trying to connect to a server, not load a file.

Comment: That's how MySQL works. You can't open a file and expect it to suddenly be a MySQL database. Like many RDBMS packages it is client/server so the only reasonable thing for that driver to do is connect to a server. SQLite is an embedded database, that's why it can do this. See also: LevelDB, GDB, etc.

Comment: I have a 38MB MySQL file. How do I import this into a new SQLite database?

Comment: You can't do that directly. You need to restore it to a MySQL database server first, then use a conversion tool of some kind to convert it. Since MySQL and SQLite have substantially different features you may find you can't convert your database without considerable changes. If it's a very elementary schema it's *possible* you could load it directly into SQLite, but that's rarely the case.

Comment: Okay, I was trying to get a baseball stats database. I found one in sqlite. Thank you for your help!